# Every that emits several times?

Tags: rxjs, reactive

I tried the following code that use ngrx as source observable.

```
this.continue$ = this.store.select(s => s.cart)
  .switchMap( cart => Observable.from(cart.items) )
  .every( item => item.amount > 0 && item.amount <= item.max_amount )
```

What I am trying to do is, every time that a new `Cart` is emitted, test all items in that `Cart` and emit a boolean if every item pass a certain condition.

I tried using the `every()` operation, but now I understand that `every()` will never emit something because the source observable never completes. (and if it completes, `every()` will emit only one time because that is how it works)

My question would be, is there a way to solve my problem, better (without the need for `subscribe`) than

```
this.store.select(s => s.cart)
  .subscribe( cart => {
    this.continue$ = Observable.from(cart.items)
      .every( item => item.amount > 0 && item.amount <= item.max_amount )
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do the job. Note, this uses `Array.every()`, I assume that `cart.items` is an array.

```
this.continue$ = this.store.select(s => s.cart)
  .map( cart => 
    cart.items.every(item =>
      item.amount > 0 && item.amount <= item.max_amount 
    )
  );
```

---

Actually, you might find this works

```
this.continue$ = this.store.select(s => 
  s.cart.items.every(item =>
   item.amount > 0 && item.amount <= item.max_amount 
  )
);
```